# In a finite permutation group where $|\mbox{fix}(g)| \le 2$ for $g \ne 1$. Properties of orbit of $O_p(G)G_{\alpha}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite permutation group acting transitive and non-regular on $\Omega$ with $|\Omega| \ge 4$. Suppose further that every nontrivial element has at most two fixed points.

> Now let $\alpha \in \Omega$ and suppose that $p \in \pi(G)$ is such that $O_p(G) \ne 1$ and that $|G_{\alpha}|$ is odd. If $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}| \le 2$, then $p = 2$ and $O_2(G) = Z(G)$. Otherwise $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}| \ge 4$.

Why does the above hold? I see that if $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}| = 2$, then as by orbit-stabilizer $2 = |O_p(G) : (O_p(G))_{\alpha}|$ we must have $p = 2$. If $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}| = 1$ then $O_p(G) \le G_{\alpha}$, which implies, as $|G_{\alpha}|$ is odd and $O_p(G) \ne 1$, that $p > 2$. So I guess this case must somehow excluded, but I have no idea how. Also why $O_2(G) = Z(G)$ I do not see, and why $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}| = 3$ is not possible?

Comment: A nontrivial normal subgroup of a transitive permutation group cannot fix any points.

Comment: Yes, thank you, as the orbits all have the same size. But what about the other points: $O_2(G) = Z(G)$ and $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}| \ne 3$?

Comment: Since $|G_\alpha|$ is odd, $|O_2(G)|=2$, so $O_2(G) \le Z(G)$. But $Z(G)$ must permute the fixed points of $G_\alpha$, of which there are at most $2$, so $|Z(G)| \le 2$. Similarly $|\alpha^{O_p(G)}|=3$ would give $p=3$, $|O_3(G)|=3$, $G_\alpha \le C_G(O_3(G))$, giving similar contradiction.

Comment: Okay, I thought about your comment, but it gives me a contradiction: If $O_3(G) = \{1,y,y^2\}$ and $\alpha^{O_3(G)} = \{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ then as $\alpha^{O_3(G)} = \alpha^{G_{\alpha}O_3(G)} = \alpha^{O_3(G)G_{\alpha}}$ the point stabilizer acts on the orbit. So for $x \in G_{\alpha}$ we must have $\beta^x = \gamma$, $\gamma^x = \beta$. Now as $O_3(G)$ is normal we have $y^x \in O_3(G)$. Suppose $\alpha^y = \beta, \beta^y = \gamma$, then $\alpha^{x^{-1}yx} = \alpha^{yx} = \beta^x = \gamma$, so we must have $y^x = y^2$, as this is the only el. mapping $\alpha$ to $\gamma$, not $y^x = y$???

Comment: $\beta^x=\gamma$, $\gamma^x=\beta$ is impossible because $|G_\alpha|$ is odd.

Comment: Okay, then this would give that $G_{\alpha}$ is trivial, hence contradicting non-regularity. But may I ask, what was your reasoning for stating $G_{\alpha} \le C_G(O_3(G))$? Just because I am curious how you arrived at this (because my reasoning would give a contradiction earlier on)?

Comment: I was thinking $|O_3(G)|=3$, hence $|{\rm Aut}(O_3(G))|=2$, but $|G_\alpha|$ is odd, so $G_\alpha$ centralizes $O_3(G)$.

Comment: Nice argument, so each element must induce the identity automorphism! Thanks for your help :)